# Couldn't find method exclude() in react-native-google-signin

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I am a newbie so I need help about my gradle dependencies when using `react-native-google-signin` library and I'm not sure if I missed it or just misstyped something because I have followed step by step from this repo:
https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/android-guide.md, but my build.gradle script cannot compile.

This is my dependencies in `app/build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-oauth')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // From react-native-sign-in
    compile project(':react-native-google-signin'){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
}
```

When I run command 'react-native run-android' in my terminal, I encounter this error:

> Could not find method exclude() for arguments
>   [{group=com.google.android.gms}] on project
>   ':react-native-google-signin' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

So that what I have should work, but I am confused why it doesn't.
Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Have you try:

```
compile(project(':react-native-google-signin')) {
  exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
 }
```